# Function in sheet has stopped working recently

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a function which up until recently was working fine.

```
    function DynamicImportRange(sheet_url, sheet_name, sheet_range) {
      var values = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheet_url).getSheetByName(sheet_name).getRange(sheet_range).getValues();
      return values
    };
```

I reference the function in a cell and am now getting the error: "You do not have permission to perform that action."  I have authorized the function in the script editor and as I said before it was working fine for a long while up until recently.  Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: have you tried this search ? it returns a few tracks to check :http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5DYou+do+not+have+permission+to+perform+that+action

Comment: I did do that search and look through some of the threads.  No info from them has helped fixed the problem though.  I find it really strange that this all of a sudden stopped working within the 2 weeks when it was working fine for months.  Has google made some kind of change recently?

Comment: They continuously change a lot of things but it generally doesn't invalidate scripts...hopefully.... That said, spreadsheets are being converted to new versions, are you sure the URL is still valid ?

Comment: Yep still valid.  Just copied and pasted to browser and it pulls the referenced sheet up.

Comment: Did someone change sheetnames (check for spaces before and after the names)? Or removed enough data to make your range bigger than the maximum number of rows/columns of the sheet?

Comment: Nope no changes.  This function was used many times within my sheet and references several different sheets yet all of them broke.  I also stubbed the function within the script with parameters that I'm passing in the sheet and it executes fine when running the script from the script interface.  The same stubbed version of the function fails to run with the aforementioned error when invoked from a cell in the sheet.

Comment: Can someone try creating a simple function like

var values = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheet_url)

and see if you can call it from a sheet without an error?  I have tried this in a new sheet I created and I cannot get it to work.

Comment: works without issue for me

Comment: Just want to clarify my steps for reproduction.

Comment: @Serge Just want to clarify my steps for reproduction.

1. Create sheet with script that has a function which calls SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl

2. use =functionname() in a cell in that sheet to invoke the function

Here is a sheet which shows the error [link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ObTMw0cBksleunIes4Js5fHDL3McLwPScW5qEZo2D8s/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

That is working for me as well. However, if it is not working for you, try doing something like this:

```
function DynamicImportRange(sheet_id, sheet_name, sheet_range) {
      var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet_id).getSheetByName(sheet_name).getRange(sheet_range).getValues();
      return values;
    };
```

The only change I made was that instead of passing `sheet_url` I'm passing `sheet_id` and it seems to be working perfectly well.

Comment: Tried using the openByID() function using the steps above and I can't seem to get it to work either.